# Elegant way to support both python and python3 in vim plugin

Tags: plugin-system, vimscript-python

I recently received a pull request to change my vim plugin to make it support python3. But these changes break the plugin for the vim on my Mac which seems to listen to python.

```
python import sys
```

versus

```
python3 import sys
```

Is there an elegant method to make the script in my plugin detect which statement it should use? Something like:

```
if has('python')
   python import ...
elseif if has('python3')
   python3 import ...
else
   finish
endif
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid rewriting the Python script, put it in a separate file and use `:pyfile` or `:py3file` instead.

```
let script_path = expand('<sfile>:p:h') . '/script.py'

if !has('python') and !has('python3')
   finish
endif

execute (has('python3') ? 'py3file' : 'pyfile') script_path
```

This will load `script.py` that's in the same directory.

Answer (score 3):

My technique for distinction of the python versions is to create a separate command (although this is in my `.vimrc` startup files, you can modify as needed for the plugin code.)

```
function! PyImports()
Py << EOF
import sys, os, .....
EOF
endfunction

if has('python')
  command! -nargs=* Py python <args>
  call PyImports()
elseif has('python3')
  command! -nargs=* Py python3 <args>
  call PyImports()
endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how [youcompleteme](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/autoload/youcompleteme.vim) does.

1. Define a function for determining whether python3 is available:

   ```
   function! s:UsingPython3()
     if has('python3')
       return 1
     endif
       return 0
   endfunction
   ```
2. then get the right python command:

   ```
   let s:using_python3 = s:UsingPython3()
   let s:python_until_eof = s:using_python3 ? "python3 << EOF" : "python << EOF"
   let s:python_command = s:using_python3 ? "py3 " : "py "
   ```